# How to make one body stick to another moving object in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have an object moving along the X-axis, while the other body rests. 
After a collision is made, I wish the resting object move along with the moving object.

I use this code to move the first body:

```
    SKAction* moveBlock = [SKAction moveByX:-distanceToMove y:0 duration:0.01 * distanceToMove];
    SKAction* removeBlock = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    _moveBlocksAndRemove = [SKAction sequence:@[moveBlock, removeBlock]];
```

and in the collision detection I have tried to set a friction:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == categoryA && secondBody.categoryBitMask == categoryB) {
            firstBody.friction = 1.0;
            secondBody.friction = 1.0;
}
```

But that didn't work. applying velocity of the first body won't work since its velocity = 0;

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? I'm having the same issue, 2 bodies stacked up, moving the one from the bottom [rectangle] on X/Y axis, while top body [circle] moves right on the Y due to the collisionBitMask, there's no link/friction happening on the X, it just stayed put on that X. Can 't use a joint since physically it's 2 separate bodies just linked together by the touching surface. I got something more or less 'working' using applyImpulse, but I want to programmatically move the rectangle using a moveby, not really an impulse.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried that but it seems you want to add `SKPhysicsJoint` to the scene:

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == categoryA && 
                 secondBody.categoryBitMask == categoryB) {
    SKPhysicsJointFixed* pin =
                    [SKPhysicsJointFixed jointWithBodyA:firstBody 
                                                  bodyB:secondBody 
                                                 anchor:firstBody.position];
    [self.physicsWorld addJoint:pin];
}
```

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. When adding this, both bodies actually ignore each other.

Comment: I think you should apply force or impulse to node's physics body instead of using `[SKAction moveByX:y:duration:]` method

Comment: Since my body is moving from side to side in the air if I apply forces to it it just falls.. and I wish to keep it moving in the air.. any idea how to solve this? If I make it non dynamic, it won't be affected by forces..

Comment: physicsbody.affectedbygravity = NO