# How to attach sprites that collide?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-engine, game-physics

I essentially want the "sprites" to collide when they stick together. However, I don't want the "joint" to be rigid; I essentially want the sprites to be able to move around as long as they are in contact with each other. Imagine two circles connected, and you can move one circle around the other, as long as it remains in contact.

I found this question: [How to make one body stick to another moving object in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083604/how-to-make-one-body-stick-to-another-moving-object-in-spritekit) and a lot of other resources that explain how to make sprites stick upon collision, but they all use SKJoints, which are rigid are not really flexible.

I guess another way to phrase it would be to say that I want the sprites to stick, but I want them to be able to "slide" on each other.

Comment: This may be what you're looking for. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKConstraint_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKConstraint/distance:toNode:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can think of one workaround, but this wouldn't work with non-normal polygons.

Sticking (pun unintended) with your circles example, what if you lock the position of the circle?

```
let circle1 = center circle
let circle2 = movable circle
```

Knowing the width of both circles, you can place in the update function that the position should be exactly the distance of:

```
((circle1.frame.width / 2) + (circle2.frame.width / 2))
```

If you're up to it, here's some code to help you on your way.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
{
    let distance = hypotf(Float(circle1.position.x - circle2.position.x), Float(circle1.position.y - circle2.position.y))
    //calculate circle distances from each other

    let radius = ((circle1.frame.width / 2) + (circle2.frame.width / 2))
    //distance of circle positions

    if distance != radius
    {
        //if distance is less or more than radius

        let pointA = circle1.position
        let pointB = circle2.position
        let pointC = CGPointMake(pointB.x + 2, pointB.y)
        let angle_ab = atan2(pointA.y - pointB.y, pointA.x - pointB.x)
        let angle_cb = atan2(pointC.y - pointB.y, pointC.x - pointB.x)
        let angle_abc = angle_ab - angle_cb
        //get angle of circles from each other using atan2

        let vectorx = cos(angle_abc)
        let vectory = sin(angle_abc)
        //convert angle into vectors

        let x = circle1.position.x + radius * vectorx
        let y = circle1.position.y + radius * vectory
        //get new coordinates from vector, radius and center circle position

        circle2.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
        //set new position
    }
}
```

Well you need to write code to make sure the movable circle, is well movable.
But, this **should** work.

I haven't tested this yet though, and I haven't even learned geometry let alone trig in school yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question as you intended it, you can still use joints- just create actions with Inverse Kinematic constraints that allow rotation and translation around the contacting circles' joint.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013017-CH1-SW72